# Identify font for the logo of web site "Les Passeurs"

Tags: fonts, font-identification, typefaces

I am trying to find the fonts used in the following Logo for web site "Les Passeurs". I've been trying to use whatthefont.com, but haven't had much success.

[image: Les Passeurs]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That could be called a Celtic or Gaelic style of lettering.

It looks like outlines based on something like [Stonehenge](http://www.dafont.com/stonehenge.font)...

[image]

...or [Celtic](http://www.fontspace.com/sam-wang/celtic) which is very similar.

That sort of thing is often seen in Irish bar signs, Father Ted opening credits...